# Android OTG Marshmallow create a file in USB drive

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, createfile, usb-otg

I'm trying to create folder in USB drive mounted using OTG. Works fine in Lollipop but I'm struggle with Marshmallow.

All permissions are given. I know SAF is the way to go about it.
And I've been trying to write custom DocumentProvider to mkdir. 
And I'm struggling..

Please help.